# Using define within define keep giving me an error.Why?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

As far as I know using define within define is allowed in certain coditions,but it gives me an error everytime.
For example:

```
(define (last-digit n) (remainder n 10))

(define (reverse-int n)
  (define (rev-iter n result)
    (if (= n 0)
        result
       (rev-iter (quotient n 10) (+ (* result 10) (last-digit n)))))
  (rev-iter n 0))
```

The error is:

```
*define: expected only one expression for the function body, but found 1 extra part*
```

and Dr.Racket marks the last row.

I literally copy small programs like this from the book and I still get an error.Where is the problem?

Comment: I tried it in DrRacket  with `#lang racket` and it works. Which language do you use?

Comment: In DrRacket 6.4 it works at least with `#lang racket`, in `R5RS`, and in `Pretty Big`. @STD: what version of DrRacket are you using?

Comment: 6.3 version,from the language tab I chose some lang dialect and now it works,thank you guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DrRacket has support for many surface languages. You are using one of the teaching languages that are related to Scheme but doesn't include the whole language.

In the dropdown at the bottom left. Select "Determine language from source", then add as the first line one of:

```
#!racket
#!r5rs
#!r6rs
```

The first line tells DrRacket how to read the program and what should be available in the beginning. Using Scheme or Pretty Big in the dropdown chooses a legacy language and it's **not** standard Scheme at all. Using "Determine language from source" is the best way to go. Which to choose depends greatly on which tutorial you are following and what (non standard) features you are ok with. Find out what standard you are supposed to be using and set the first line accordingly.

`#!racket` is DrRacket's own version of a language dialect of Scheme and what DrRacket is written in. It is mostly compatible with R5RS but has some differences that are incompatible with all the Scheme standards.

`#!r5rs` and `#!r6rs` corresponds to the R5RS and R6RS standard reports. DrRacket has a no thrills implementation of both where the reports are implemented in the strictest sense. Eg. an R5RS program that works under

`#!r5rs` in DrRacket would most likely work on all other R5RS compliant implementation as long as you only use valid identifiers (eg. no symbols starting with `#%` in your program)

For `#!r6rs` you need at least one import so you can just add `(import (rnrs))` as the second line and you have most of the R6RS language available.

`#!r6rs` works the same way as R5RS except DrRacket exposes it's module system. As long as you keep to your own libraries and the standard libraries it's portable, but if you import libraries designed to work in `#!racket` you might be faced with having to convert data structures to make it work and you cannot expect it to work on any other implementation of R6RS.

Latest version of Scheme, R7RS, isn't available in DrRacket yet.